# multithreading in python unittest

Tags: python, multithreading, unit-testing

I need to write an automation test for network connection for two separated primitive modules  server and client. Can't use socket server.
Content of server.py

```
import socket    
def sniff_pack():    

    sock = socket.socket()    

    sock.bind(('', 9999))    
    sock.listen(1)    
    conn, addr = sock.accept()    

    print 'connected:', addr    

    while True:    
        data = conn.recv(1024)    
        if not data:    
            break    
        conn.send(data.upper())    

    conn.close()    

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    sniff_pack()
```

Content of client.py

```
import socket    

def send_pack():    
    adress = 'localhost'    
    port = 9999    
    sock = socket.socket()    
    sock.connect((adress, port))    
    sock.send('hello, world!')    

    data = sock.recv(1024)    
    sock.close()    

    return data    

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    send_pack()
```

Haven't succeed with threading.
Any idea how to fight GIL  in following?

```
from server import sniff_pack    
from client import send_pack    
import unittest    

class PackTestCase(unittest.TestCase):    

    def setUp(self):    
        sniff_pack()    

    def test_proper_pack(self):    
        self.assertEqual(send_pack(),'HELLO, WORLD!')    

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    unittest.main()
```